# NSFileManager removeItemAtPath: error: did not actually free disk space

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL* url = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString* directory = [url path];
NSString* filePath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
}
```

Here's my code. When it is executed, the file is deleted, but the space remains occupied. Here's the code for storing something into the file.

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL* url = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString* directory = [url path];
NSString* filePath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];
NSArray* oldArray = nil;
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    oldArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
}
NSMutableArray* mergeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayOfPersons];
[mergeArray addObjectsFromArray:oldArray];
if ( [mergeArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) NSLog(@"Written");
```

By the way, it cost 1 MB to store an array with only 1 object(an NSDictionary with 2 keys). Is there a cheaper way to store it?

Comment: I used this exact code and it worked just fine.  Also a dictionary with two keys and two objects was 264 bytes.

Comment: instead of nil pass an `NSError` object to `[fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];` for error argument and check what it says.

Comment: you means you execut the code , the files exist? Or the files are deleted but the the space remains occupied?

Comment: @cloosen, the file does not exist, but the space remains occupied

Comment: @borrrden, in my case, 1MB, the two object being an NSString and an NSNumber.The code works fine, but the space remains occupied.

Comment: oh my god , the file does not exist, but the space remains occupied...you test with the iphone or simulator?I have ever code like this ,but never notice the occupy of the hard disk

Comment: How are you measuring the storage space usage?

Comment: @CarlVeazey, by settings->general->usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be much more careful with your experiments.  The unix file system does lots of stuff with files.  In fact, when you "delete" a file, all you do is unlink it from the file system.  If that file is open with another file descriptor, anywhere in the OS, it will remain open.

Furthermore, there are lots of optimizations to reuse file nodes.  Just because you delete a file, does not mean that space goes back automatically.  It could be "reserved" in your app for several reasons, for other files to use.  No sense giving it back to the file system until the file system needs it.

`settings->general->usage` is a very rough measurement of file system utilization.  A better measurement would be accessing the attributes of the file and file system directly.

Using your code as a base, consider this:

```
- (NSString*)workingDirectory {
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL* url = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory
                                      inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    return [url path];
}

- (NSString*)filePath {
    return [[self workingDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];
}
```

Now, you can see all the attributes of the entire file system with this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
    attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[self workingDirectory] error:0];
NSLog(@"file system attributes: %@", attributes);
```

and those for the specific file with this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
    attributesOfItemAtPath:[self filePath] error:0];
NSLog(@"file attributes: %@", attributes);
```

Pay attention to `NSFileSystemFreeSize` and `NSFileSize`.

Run your app, and dump both of these values.  Create your file, and dump them again.  Delete the file, and dump them again.

After all that, you may actually see the `NSFileSystemFreeSize` go UP, even after the delete.  Remember, the system itself is creating temporary files, and is probably caching those file system nodes for future use.

You can get more consistent results if you quit all other apps.  Then, quit yours (double-click power button, X all running apps).  Delete the file before doing this.

1. Now, start your app, without the file existing.
2. Dump file system data.
3. Create the file.
4. Dump file system data.
5. Dump file data.

You should see the file taking up about 200-250 bytes, and the file system free size should drop 8192.

1. Delete the file.
2. Dump file system data.  Is probably at least as big as it was before deleting file.
3. Quit app (not in XCode -- double-click power, X the app).
4. Run the app.
5. Dump file system data.  You should see the data back to about what it was when you started earlier.

---

In conclusion, while it may look like the file system has not released the data, it really has, but maybe the tool you are using to query just does not know the details of the file system.

Note, also, that when an app is running, it will use lots of file system resources for stuff that you are not explicitly doing.

I hope that made sense...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I cannot see the data back to when I started earlier since it seems that this data is changing all the time. But I do get some similar result as you said. Could you explain further to me why 'You should see the file taking up about 200-250 bytes, and the file system free size should drop 8192.'. (In my case the file 410 bytes and free size dropped 16384.) Why I lose so much space while my file is actually small? How do I save my disk space? For now, an array of 100 objects costs me hundreds of MBs.

Comment: You are worried about something you have no control over.  For efficiency, the file system works in blocks of bytes.  The file system manages space for all apps, and tries to keep potential data for files close together.  Make sure you write good, efficient code, and do not worry about the implementation of the file system itself.  Even if it sucks (which is does not) there is nothing you can do about it.  As for your 100 objects, make sure they are efficient.  You control the specific file size, not necessarily exactly what the file system allots.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to delete the file looks correct, but you are switching between URLs and Paths when you don't need to.  You should also be checking for an error when you try to delete the file so that you can see why it doesn't work.  Try this:

```
    NSFileManager   *fileManager    = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray         *directoryURLs  = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory 
                                                          inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSURL           *directoryURL   = [directoryURLs objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL           *fileURL        = [directoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];
    if (!fileURL)
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not create URL for file.");
        return;
    }

    NSError *err = nil;
    if (![fileURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err])
    {
        NSLog(@"File is not reachable.\n"
               "Error: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }

    err = nil;
    [fileManager removeItemAtURL:fileURL error:&err];
    if (err)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to delete existing file.\n"
              "Error: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise. Unfortunately, the error is nil after     [fileManager removeItemAtURL:fileURL error:&err]. The file is deleted. But the space remains occupied.

Comment: Ahh, that would be a different question!

Answer (score 0):

May it be, that the length of the ˚FILE_NAME` is greater or equal to 300 chars? This brought me to similar issues with NSFileManager some time ago...

Comment: I think it is within 300, "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/4E0DED61-2FE1-4337-8F0B-461E35B1E610/Library/Caches/receiversSent"