# How can I delete image from file system storage correctly? Issue with iOS only

Tags: codenameone

In my app I allow the user to capture or select an image from gallery to set as the background for a container. The image is scaled  and then saved. The user can replace or remove this image later and so the old/deleted image needs to be removed.

To Save I use; -

```
           img = Image.createImage(filePath);
            int i_longSide = Math.max(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight());
            img = img.scaledWidth(i_longSide / 2);
            OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + Name + ".jpg");
            ImageIO.getImageIO().save(img, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 0.9f);
            os.close();
```

To Remove is use; -

```
if(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + Name +".jpg")){
                    FileSystemStorage.getInstance().delete(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + Name +".jpg");
}
```

When using an Android device I can see the data increase in size when an image is added and also decrease back to the original size when the image is removed. However with an iOS device, the data size does not return to the original value when an image is removed, so there is an increase each time an image is added and removed. How can I handle removing images better so that the iOS app works as well as the Android?

Comment: Does the code enter the `exists` block? After deletion does the `exists` condition return `false`? Assuming yes to both I would guess this relates to the way iOS calculates space. This is a problem on Mac OS too. You can delete files and empty the trash but storage size remains fixed in the UI sometimes until a reboot. Apple does a lot of creative things on top of the storage (backup, search indexing etc.) and it creates some odd problems like these.

Comment: Yes to both questions on ```exists```.  So this is likely not a real problem? I tried to reboot the device and not change in the size of the 'Documents & Data' folder.

Comment: It's probably some Apple oddity with their filesystem but searching for this I can't find anything. How are you checking the app size? Maybe searching for that methodology will yield a way to compact the app.

Comment: I check the app size simply by going to settings -> General -> iPhone Storage -> click on the app in list. From there you see the App Size and Documents and Data. Documents and Data is what I am referring to

Comment: This seems to be OK and consistent according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12326998/756809). Try this: create a file that takes up space. Delete it. Then create a file that takes the exact same amount of space. If the app takes up the initial amount of space then the deletion worked, if it takes double the amount of space then there might be a problem.

Comment: To test this, I add an image from gallery which adds 3MB. When I remove this image 1MB is reduced Leaving 2MB. I add the same image and the size goes to 5MB. When I remove the image again the size again reduces by 1MB to 4MB. So each time there is a net increase of 2MB. If I ensure my app is the only app running, the result is still the same.

Comment: That's weird, I'm guessing there's some backup or indexing that triggers this growth but I'm not sure what we can do. Notice that the underlying IOS APIs we use are identical to the ones used in the question/answer I linked above.